# Angular 2: Call function from a string name

Tags: function, angular, typescript, eventemitter

I'm not sure is it question related to Angular 2 or more to Typescript itself. But anyway, I have a component which emits object

```
<grid" (gridButtonClickEvent)="gridEvent($event)"></grid>
```

Here is how I catching the event

```
private gridEvent(event) {
    console.log(event);
}
```

Here is the the event format of what I'm getting.

```
{Key: value}
```

So basically it's a simple object.
I want to call a function with name `Key` and pass a `value` as an argument, how is it possible? The object `Key` would be different, but I know all possible variants and already registered function in my component.

```
private Key() {}
```

I was trying something like this

```
private gridEvent(event) {
    let eventName = Object.keys(event)[0];
    window[eventName]();
}
```

But it says

```
window[eventName] is not a function
```

Comment: 1. Do you have this event as a property on your `window`? 2. Why would you do things like that? Isn't that simpler to just pass a function as an object property?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try this:

```
private gridEvent(event) {
    let methodName = Object.keys(event)[0];
    if(this[methodName]) {
        // method exists in the component
        let param = event[methodName];
        this[methodName](param); // call it
    }
}
```

More intuitive way would be to construct your emitting object as:

```
{ methodName: 'method1', methodParam: someValue }
```

Then in the component:

```
private gridEvent(event) {
    let methodName = event.methodName;
    if(this[methodName]) {
        // method exists on the component
        let param = event.methodParam;
        this[methodName](param); // call it
    }
}
```

However, I'd personally avoid doing it this way if not really necessary. Rather emit an action that should be triggered and then do some switch statement to call the appropriate method instead. A dumber approach, but easier to reason about I'd say.

Comment: Really useful and simple solution. Works like a charm in Angular 6. Thank you!