# Call function from a string name

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to call an Angular function with the function's string name but angular is throwing an error.

```
const functionName = 'getFilelist';
if (this[functionName]) {
  this[functionName]();
}
```

[image]

Comment: You seem to do it like described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42108530/angular-2-call-function-from-a-string-name I think we might need to see a bit more code. Where do you execute this codesnippet?

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a type assertion here so TypeScript knows that the key you are calling is on the object you are trying to index.

For example, `this[functionName as keyof typeof ApplicationFormComponent]`. This should tell TypeScript you are accessing a proper element on the class.

Answer (score 1):

The following code snippet should work. Just declare the type of `functionName` as `keyof ApplicationFormComponent`.

```js
test() {
  const functionName: keyof ApplicationFormComponent = 'getFilelist';
  if (this[functionName]) {
    this[functionName]();
  }
}
```